# How to process messages outside GCP in a Kafka server running on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka, google-compute-engine, kafka-consumer-api

I have been trying to run a consumer in my local machine connecting to a Kafka server running inside GCP.

Kafka and Zookeeper is running on the same GCP VM instance

**Step 1: Start Zookeeper**

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

**Step 2: Start Kafka**

```
bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

If I run a consumer inside the GCP VM instance it works fine:

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --from-beginning
```

I verified the firewall rules, and I have access from my local machine, I can reach both the public IP and the port the Kafka server is running on.

I tested many options, changing the server.properties of kafka, for example:

```
advertised.host.name=public-ip
```

or

```
advertised.listeners=public-ip
```

Following the answer on [connecting-kafka-running-on-ec2-machine-from-my-local-machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43565698/connecting-kafka-running-on-ec2-machine-from-my-local-machine) without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the official [documentation](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs):

**advertised.listeners**

> Listeners to publish to ZooKeeper for clients to use. In IaaS environments, this may
>   need to be different from the interface to which the broker binds. If
>   this is not set, the value for listeners will be used. Unlike
>   listeners it is not valid to advertise the 0.0.0.0 meta-address.

After testing many different options, this solution worked for me:

Setting up two listeners, one **EXTERNAL** with the public IP, and one **INTERNAL** with the private IP:

```
# Configure protocol map
listener.security.protocol.map=INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT

# Use plaintext for inter-broker communication
inter.broker.listener.name=INTERNAL

# Specify that Kafka listeners should bind to all local interfaces
listeners=INTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9027,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9037

# Separately, specify externally visible address
advertised.listeners=INTERNAL://localhost:9027,EXTERNAL://kafkabroker-n.mydomain.com:9093
```

Explanation:

> In many scenarios, such as when deploying on AWS, the externally
>   advertised addresses of the Kafka brokers in the cluster differ from
>   the internal network interfaces that Kafka uses.

Also remember to set up your firewall rule to expose the port on the **EXTERNAL** listener in other to connect to it from an external machine.

> Note: It's important to restrict access to authorized clients only.
>   You can use network firewall rules to restrict access. This guidance
>   applies to scenarios that involve both RFC 1918 and public IP;
>   however, when using public IP addresses, it's even more important to
>   secure your Kafka endpoint because anyone can access it.

Taken from [google solutions](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/processing-messages-from-kafka-hosted-outside-gcp).

Comment: This blog also explains the concept: https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc

Comment: when you say listeners=INTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9027,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9037, am I supposed to replace the word INTERNAL with my internal IP and External with my external IP, for e.g. listeners = 10.153.0.3://0.0.0.0:9027, 31.83.170.127://0.0.0.0:9037 ?

Comment: no, just the IP ADDRESSES AFTER the INTERNAL and EXTERNAL words.

advertised.listeners=INTERNAL://localhost:9027,EXTERNAL://kafkabroker-n.mydomain.com:9093

localhost:9027 -> You probably will keep it as localhost, unless you are using some DNS resolver, might need to change the port.

kafkabroker-n.mydomain.com:9093 -> This will most likely change with your own external IP or DNS.